# How to rearrange rxgraph's position of node?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because some node is too far when I capture the screen for most important part.

How to move the node's position to the proper location?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10675/how-to-rearrange-rxgraph%27s-position-of-node?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think rxgraph allows you to move nodes around (though that would be a welcome contribution).  If you can't see all the nodes, you can left-click and drag the window around to pan and use the mouse scroll wheel to zoom.

---

Originally posted by [sglaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/46/sglaser/) with karma: 649 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-21**:
Thank you~Zooming window can see all the nodes, but the size is very small to capture the screen sometimes just unseen if open some packages like gazebo. So I want to rearrange all the important nodes for me to put together to a near location to express some ideas.